# Постоянно падает postgresql с ошибкой "FATAL: sorry, too many clients already"

Tags: linux, postgresql

Постоянно падает postgresql c ошибкой:

> ```
> FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
> ```

Примерно в один и тот же час с утра, около 7 часов.
В это время не наблюдается каких-то пиковых нагрузок или много клиентов.
Параметры:

- `MaxConnection=1000`,
- `shared_buffers = 2048M`

Comment: Он не падает, он отпинывает 1001-го клиента.

Comment: Тогда до какого уровня нужно поднять MaxConnection?
И когда уходят например 5 или 6 клиентов, почему postgress не поднимается?

Comment: Каждое соединение потребляет некоторое количество ресурсов сервера. Можете поднимать до тех пор, пока ресурсов у вас хватает. Но если исчерпаете ресурсы, то он действительно может упасть.

Comment: Правильнее подбирать значение максимального количества соединений соответствующее условиям эксплуатации сервера. Судя по указанному вами значению, вы занимаетесь хостингом?

Comment: Меня просто смущает то, что не может быть на сайте одновременно столько пользователей в это время. А если и так, то когда уходит 998-999 почему postgresql не поднимается? Нужно рестартовать службу.

Comment: Если сайт хорошо написан, то использует одно соединение независимо от количества пользователей.

Comment: Сайт не беке использует Django и база стандартная под него. За сутки с сайтом все хорошо, а только с утра падает postgresql. Ладно, буду разбираться.

Comment: У меня на серваке хостится почти 20 клиентских проектов на Django, но в совокупности они используют только 50 соединений. Несмотря на то, что на некоторые из них нагрузка около 300 rps. Просто укажите параметр [CONN_MAX_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-CONN_MAX_AGE) чтобы не открывалось отдельное соединение на каждый запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем. Результат отпишу.

Comment: я бы ещё попробовал помониторить текущие соединения постгресса в течение суток...

Comment: Добавили параметр CONN_MAX_AGE, но сегодня с утра, примерно в то же время сайт снова упал с той же ошибкой базы.

Comment: Посмотрите на результаты `SELECT * from pg_stat_activity` во время проблемы (заранее откройте соединение, конечно же).

Answer (score 2):

Варианта два:

1. В БД приходит клиентов больше, чем [max_connections](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/enterprise/9.6/runtime-config-connection). Нужно, увеличивая время от времени значение этой опции добиться стабильной работы.
2. Обращающееся в постгрес приложение имеет баг, который позволяет плодить подключения к базе. Может быть у вас утром какой-то хитрый бэкап выполняется?